# Open a file from pc into tkinter

Tags: python, getopenfilename

It is possible to open a file in tkinter from pc using right click->Open with->My Program.
I just want the file path when using this method.

Comment: Sure, you can use RegEdit to create a "Open With" option. That answer isn't specific to Python or tkinter, though.... What do you mean "get the file path"?

Comment: To simplify what I want. I have a GUI with Listbox in it. Let's say I want to open a txt file with my program. All I want to do is to get the txt file path and insert it to my Listbox. I dont want the content of the txt file, only the path. I know about filedialog but I wanted to do with right click txt file->Open with->My Program

Comment: Assuming windows, you need to convert your app to an exe, or use `python.exe script.py %1`. See example here https://idojo.co/how-to-add-custom-open-with-command-to-windows-context-menu/

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a file using the method you are asking for( right-click > Open with > My Program) but you can create a program to open and edit files within a GUI using the `Tkinter file dialog` library and the `open()`  function.

An example of the Method I am talking about:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

windows = Tk()
windows.title("File Dialog Example")
windows.geometry("500x500")


def file_open():
    text_window.delete('1.0', END)
    filePath = askopenfilename(
        initialdir='C:/', title='Select a File', filetype=(("Text File", ".txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    with open(filePath, 'r+') as askedFile:
        fileContents = askedFile.read()

    text_window.insert(INSERT, fileContents)
    print(filePath)


open_button = Button(windows, text="Open File", command=file_open).grid(row=4, column=3)
text_window = Text(windows, bg="white",width=200, height=150)
text_window.place(x=50, y=50)

windows.mainloop()
```

And in order to save the changes to the file, you can read the contents in the Text Box and then write the contents to the Opened file.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know about filedialog.